# Do all LLVM PHI instructions in the same basic block always have the same set of incomming blocks?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I notice that in LLVM bitcode files, all PHI instructions in the same basic block often have the same set of incoming blocks.

Does anyone know if it is always true for all LLVM bitcode files?

Or is there any optimization pass for doing so?

For example, here is my C code:

```
// test.c

int main(){
  int **p, *q;
  int *a, *b, c, d;

  p = &a;

  if (p) {
    if (c) {
      q = &c;
    }
  }
  else{
    p = &b;
    q = &d;
  }
  if (d) {
    *p = q;
  }
}
```

After being compiled by `clang` and `opt`:

```
clang -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -c -emit-llvm test.c
opt -mem2reg test.bc -o test.opt.bc
```

Here is the output `test.opt.bc`, where all PHI instructions in block 12 have the same incomming blocks 11 and 12:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %2 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  %5 = icmp ne i32** %1, null
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %11

6:                                                ; preds = %0
  %7 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %8 = icmp ne i32 %7, 0
  br i1 %8, label %9, label %10

9:                                                ; preds = %6
  br label %10

10:                                               ; preds = %9, %6
  br label %12

11:                                               ; preds = %0
  br label %12

12:                                               ; preds = %11, %10
  %.01 = phi i32** [ %1, %10 ], [ %2, %11 ]
  %.1 = phi i32* [ %3, %10 ], [ %4, %11 ]
  %13 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %14 = icmp ne i32 %13, 0
  br i1 %14, label %15, label %16

15:                                               ; preds = %12
  store i32* %.1, i32** %.01, align 8
  br label %16

16:                                               ; preds = %15, %12
  ret i32 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

It directly follows from the `phi` instruction description from the [language reference](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i-phi):

> After this, the ‘phi’ instruction takes a list of pairs as arguments, with one pair for each predecessor basic block of the current block.

Since all of `phi` instructions in question belong to the same basic block, these lists of pairs should reference the same set of predecessors.

Comment: Oh, right! Thank you so much for the reference! :-)